# Cannot retrieve container for XShape in LibreOffice

Tags: c#, libreoffice, openoffice.org, openoffice-impress, libreoffice-impress

I'm struggling with some code using `LibreOffice 7.1.0` on `Windows 10` to append images from a folder into separate slides in `Impress`. I've been looking [here](http://fivedots.coe.psu.ac.th/%7Ead/jlop/#draw) and [OpenOffice](https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/drawing/BitmapTable.html) documentation. This call continuously fails `(null)`: `xMultiServiceFactory.createInstance("com.sun.star.drawing.BitmapTable");` and I cannot understand why? I tried using `XMultiComponentFactory` also, but no luck. Has it got something to do with `Slide Layout`, but despite being of blank type, I could drag-drop an image and it gets added in the slide.
Unfortunately, full code is on restricted system, so I have this much only. Any hints on potential causes would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It was simple issue: I needed to initialize `xMultiServiceFactory` with `xComponent`. I had earlier initialized it with `xComponentContext.getServiceManager()`. I realize again, this is why learning object model is very important. COM could get tricky unless, one knew what they were doing.